# forEach() method - looping over an array

Tags: javascript, loops

I am totally new to coding so my question is probably very basic. I want to loop over the following array and every time the number is divisible by 3 I want to add 100. If not, just print the number. I want to do that with the forEach() method. This is my code but when I want to print it it says "undefined" What am I doing wrong?

```js
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139];

test.forEach(function(num){
    if(num %3 === 0){
        return num+=100; 
    }else{
        return num; 
    }

   console.log(num) ;
})
```

Comment: [`.forEach()` method always returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since you are new to coding, just wanted to make a quick summary of the good answers you already have: if your intention is just print out the numbers, `forEach` works just fine, no need to use `map`. If you want to transform the numbers and use the transformed numbers somewhere else, `map` is more appropriate. You may also want to search for "immutability" to understand why `map` may be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! All the input was so useful.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statements:

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller.

Therefore it will never make it to the `console.log` line (this is what they call [unreachable code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code) since there is no possible path to it):

```js
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
  19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
  6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139
];

test.forEach(function(num) {
  if (num % 3 === 0) {
    num += 100;
  }

  console.log(num);
})
```

I removed the else block because, as pointed out in the comments below, there is no purpose for it.

The approach above is fine if all you want to do is log the result, but if you want to get a new array that has stored all the new values then you should consider using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
  19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
  6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139
];

var updatedValues = test.map(num => num % 3 === 0 ? num + 100 : num);

console.log(updatedValues);
```

Comment: You can also remove that `else` statement there, since it doesn't do anything with `num` ;)

Comment: Note that this modifies the local variable `num`. It does not modify the array.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `return` keyword immediately stops the function, so you don't progress further. And since [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) itself doesn't return anything, the keyword is pretty useless. You can just remove it and you'd get the behaviour you want:

```js
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139];

test.forEach(function(num){
    if(num %3 === 0){
        num+=100; 
    }

   console.log(num) ;
})
```

If you instead want to create a new array from the first one using the rules you've described, then you can simply substitute `.forEach` for the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139];

var result = test.map(function(num){
    if(num %3 === 0){
        return num+=100; 
    }else{
        return num; 
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `map` instead of `forEach` here since `map` will execute the provided function to each array item and return a new array.

> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Just changing your current code, it can be like this

```
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139];

var result = test.map(function(num) {
  if (num %3 === 0) {
    return num + 100; 
  } else {
    return num; 
  }
})
```

Or, you can also improve it further by separating things

```
const add100IfDividableBy3 = function (num) {
  return (num % 3 === 0) ? num + 100 : num;
}

const test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4, 19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299, 6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139];

const result = test.map(add100IfDividableBy3)
```

The function `add100IfDividableBy3` uses what is called as a [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I agree that `map` is probably what OP will need in a real case scenario, but the question specifies the need to **print the numbers**, which is missing in your answer, thus modifying the expected result. Maybe you could edit the answer to explain why use `map` over `forEach` and how to print the numbers :)

Comment: I upvoted Tom O answer as it's more complete, and better takes into account the actual issue the OP was having.